# Overriding external print files with another print file for only specific settings

Tags: ibm-midrange

We are in the process of transitioning our old O-spec RPG programs to use external printer files instead.  As a company, we have some standard programs and procedures we use to allow users to email or print a particular spool file when they run a program as well as set duplex, number of copies, etc.  These procedures perform various overrides on the generated spool file to change the OUTQ, number of COPIES, etc.  We also override the printer file to a standard print file we have defined like so:

```
OVRPRTF FILE(MYOUTPUT) TOFILE(PRTF132);
```

This works great for the old O specs.  However now that we are transitioning over to external printer files, we run into issues with the spool file generation.  It's hard to describe the particular issue because the output file is just a mess.  Lines are overwriting each other, the routing data doesn't change as expected, etc.  I've tracked this down to the wholesale override using `TOFILE` because I can run the override like so:

```
OVRPRTF FILE(MYOUTPUT) LPI(8) CPI(13.3) OUTQ(MYOUTQ);
```

When I do that, everything prints out great.

Ultimately, I would like the ability to use only specific overrides from the `PRTF132` override file such as the LPI, CPI, and OUTQ values.  Something like the following:

```
OVRPRTF FILE(MYOUTPUT) FROMFILE(PRTF132) LPI CPI OUTQ;
```

I know that isn't real syntax.  I've tried scouring the documentation and Googling around but came up empty.  Is this possible or do I need to roll another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the output file is just a mess. Lines are overwriting each other...

are you using SPACEB() or SPACEA() at the beginning of your line print? if not, what would explain over writting.

> Ultimately, I would like the ability to use only specific overrides from the PRTF132...

I'd propose you to

1. Retrieve Printer File attributes with API QDFRPRTA. Look at the documentation here: [Retrieve Printer File Attributes (QDFRPRTA) API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/qdfrprta.htm)
2. With the retrieved attributes perform your OVRPRTF FILE(MYOUTPUT) LPI(&LPI) CPI(&CPI) OUTQ(&MYOUTQ)

Please post the source code of your PRTF so I can look at it and test it on my system.

Comment: Yes there are SPACEA and SPACEB entries.  As I stated above, the printout looks fine so long as I override the settings individually.  It's when I override using `TOFILE` that it gets messed up.  I think the API you posted will do the trick.  Let me try it out and if it works, I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: Did you check if there is another Override already active when the program runs? DSPOVR, or shift+esc+enter -> #14.

Comment: Yes I did.  There is no other override.  I can run the overrides straight from the command prompt and then run the program without any of our routing programs and I run into the same issues.  I suspect the issue lies in the way our standard print files were initially created.  I manually created another one in my personal library with the same settings as the standard ones and ran into the same issue.  I'd have to spend a lot of time figuring out exactly what's wrong and then recreate a whole pile of standard printer files and I don't have the time for that now so your solution works great.

Comment: I’m glad that you figured it out!